# SELECT count based on columns value

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this

```
Date  | Name  | StateData |
------+-------+-----------+    
xxxxx | Tom   | OPENED    |
xxxxx | David | NULL      |
xxxxx | Tom   | NULL      |
xxxxx | Brand | CLOSED    |
xxxxx | Brand | NULL      |
xxxxx | Brand | OPENED    |
```

What result I want to achieve is something like this

```
Date | Name | OPENED | CLOSED | UNUSED |
-----+------+--------+--------+--------+
xxxxx| Tom  |   1    |    0   |    1   |
xxxxx| David|   0    |    0   |    1   |
xxxxx| Brand|   1    |    1   |    1   |
```

I've tried something like this

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    [OPENED] = COUNT(CASE WHEN StateData ='OPENED' THEN StateData END),
    [CLOSED] = COUNT(CASE WHEN StateData ='CLOSED' THEN StateData END),
    [UNUSED] = COUNT(CASE WHEN StateData IS NULL THEN StateData END)
FROM 
    [dbo].[StateData]
GROUP BY
    Name
```

the result is that I don't have at least duplicate records in Name column, but I can clearly see with simple select count(*) that the counts in the columns are not right.

First of all I did google some samples, and made the SELECT above.

Comment: You want `Opened = CASE StateData WHEN 'Opened' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`, and then `SUM` those columns -- that last bit is the crucial thing missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `SUM()` instead.  You have a problem with `NULL`:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN StateData = 'OPENED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as opened
       SUM(CASE WHEN StateData = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as closed
       SUM(CASE WHEN StateData IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unused
FROM [dbo].[StateData]
GROUP BY Name;
```

Your `unused` will always be zero because `COUNT(NULL)` is always zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "simple" pivot. Personally, however, I prefer using a Cross Tab, rather than the restrictive `PIVOT` operator:

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Name],
       COUNT(CASE StateData WHEN 'OPENED' THEN 1 END) AS OPENED,
       COUNT(CASE StateData WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END) AS CLOSED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN StateData IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS UNUSED
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date],
         [Name];
```

Note, that the version of SQL Server you've tagged (2008) is now completely unsupported. It's therefore highly recommended you look at upgrade paths as soon as possible.

Comment: Beating Gordon by 11 seconds is worth a +1. But I'm up-voting his, too, because I always use the express `ELSE 0` in conditional aggregation. :)

Comment: The problem with me using `ELSE 0` in this example would be that I'm using `COUNT` not `SUM` though, @EricBrandt; so it would give this wrong counts. :)

Comment: Darn you and your “being right”! I’m still upvoting Gordon cuz I want to see him break a billion.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much you are amazing, I really appreciate it. I knew something small is missing but I couldn't find what as I smashed my head off off the table few times :DD

Comment: If you used one of the answers, @Madadi , please do mark that one as the solution. It lets future readers know it was helpful, and you get reputation for it (which is really important as a new user to get those early privileges). Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu of course I will, but actually it didn't solved my problem see my last post if you can give me advice. Thanks :)

Comment: What last post? Your question was last editted yesterday @Madadi . The above does give the answer you ask for, so perhaps you should be asking a new question if you have new requirements?